# Unable to update existing calendar event using Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to update the following fields for an existing event but not updating as expected.

Fields we want to update:

1. Add and Remove Attachments
2. Update Subject and Body content.
3. Add and/or Remove mandatory/optional attendees.

Using the following code to remove an attachment:

```
await graphClient
    .Users[organizer]
    .Events[organizerEventId]
    .Attachments[attachmentId]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Using the following code to add an attachment:

```
var fileAttachment = new Microsoft.Graph.FileAttachment
{
    ODataType = attachment.odataType,
    Name = attachment.name,
    ContentBytes = attachment.contentBytes,
    ContentType = attachment.contentType
};

var response = await graphClient
    .Users[organizer]
    .Events[organizerEventId]
    .Attachments
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(fileAttachment);
```

Using the following code to update attendees:

```
var updateEvent = new Microsoft.Graph.Event
{
    Attendees = attendees
};

var resultUpdate = await graphClient
    .Users[organizer]
    .Events[organizerEventId]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(updateEvent);
```

Using the following code to update Subject and Body content:

```
var updateEvent = new Microsoft.Graph.Event
{
    HasAttachments = true,
    ResponseRequested = false,
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body
};

var resultUpdate = await graphClient
    .Users[organizer]
    .Events[organizerEventId]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(updateEvent);
```

I am executing the above codes in sequential order but when I debugged the code I observed that it only executes the first logic to remove attachment and call comes out without executing the remaining code logic written below in the same method.

Comment: What exception is it throwing after the first call?

Comment: No exception throwing...

Comment: @MarcLaFleur How do we update a `Date` field? The issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63480033/1232087).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root cause of this issue and fixed it.
Actually, the issue was with the async function call. I was trying to call an async function from a non-async function like below:

```
public void CreateEvent(type parameter1, type parameter2)
{    
     objMyServiceClass.CreateEvent(parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

I changed the above code to the below code because CreateEvent in MyServiceClass was an async function. Now it started working correctly.

```
public void CreateEvent(type parameter1, type parameter2)
{    
     Task.Run(async () => await objMyServiceClass.CreateEvent(parameter1, parameter2));
}
```

I know, it was a very silly mistake but sometimes we developers struggle to find such a silly mistake and ending up with a nightmare. I hope it may help someone.
Thanks!

Comment: Thank your for sharing your solution and its explanation. You may want to mark your response as an `Answer`. Doing so may help more users (like myself). Readers generally pay more attention to an accepted answer.

Comment: How do we update a `Date` field? The issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63480033/1232087) - in case you have time to comment/suggest an idea.

Comment: @nam, I have provided answer in your question. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: @nam, if you give a vote to my question, it would be good.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: This question was created by me only. You can go to the top of this page and vote.